# How to change or customize JBehave step?

Tags: spring, jbehave

I have slight issue with step customization. I want to add some specific data from Spring context to JBehave report after successful step executing, e.g. I have step:

`When login as random user`

I want to see in report if all was good something like

`When login as random user (%username%)`

I found how to execute any logic before/after story/scenario, but  I can't find correct way how to add any logic after step and how can I customize/extend basic JBehave steps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StoryReporter` API:

```java
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.NullStoryReporter;

public class MyCustomStoryReporter extends NullStoryReporter {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(String step) {
        // add "before-step" logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void successful(String step) {
        // add "after-passed-step" logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(String step, Throwable cause) {
        // add "after-failed-step" logic here
    }
}
```

More information on `StoryReporter` and its configuration can be found in the official documentation: [Reporting Stories](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html)